# does the set method in ArrayList actually change in memory?

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures

I have an array of ArrayLists. I'm iterating over them using a variable called 'al' and changing the contents of that arraylist. However, I see that the contents of the original array of ArrayList have changed. Why is this?

I was expecting that since I am only changing the contents of a new variable called 'al', the contents of the original array of ArrayLists, ie alal wouldn't change.

Are these operating on memory directly? What is this concept called, if I would like to read a bit more about it.

```
    package proj;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Ask
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            myArrayList1.add(1);
            myArrayList1.add(1);
            myArrayList1.add(1);

            ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            myArrayList2.add(2);
            myArrayList2.add(2);
            myArrayList2.add(2);

            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> alal = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
            alal.add(myArrayList1);
            alal.add(myArrayList2);

            for(ArrayList<Integer> al : alal)
            {
                al.set(0, 99);
            }

            System.out.println(alal);
        }
    }
```

EDIT : I'm trying to edit my code based on SMA's post so that my contents still remain the same even upon using the set method. This is what I have tried, but my output still reflects the change [[99, 1, 1], [99, 2, 2]]

```
package proj;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Ask
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        myArrayList1.add(1);
        myArrayList1.add(1);
        myArrayList1.add(1);

        ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        myArrayList2.add(2);
        myArrayList2.add(2);
        myArrayList2.add(2);

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> alal = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        alal.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(myArrayList1));//creating seperate instance of array list with same content as original list
        alal.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(myArrayList2));
        for(ArrayList<Integer> al : alal)
        {
            al.set(0, 99);
        }
        System.out.println(alal);
    }
}
```

EDIT 2 : However, I don't see the same behavior in a normal ArrayList. Here the contents remain as [1, 2, 3] even after editing them to 99 inside the loop. So, are new instances of these variables created here? Aren't they mere references as before?

```
package proj;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Ask
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        myArrayList.add(1);
        myArrayList.add(2);
        myArrayList.add(3);

        for(int element : myArrayList)
        {
            element = 99;
        }

        System.out.println(myArrayList);

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the Java for each loop work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was expecting that since I am only changing the contents of a new variable called 'al'

`alal` contains references to `ArrayList`s. When you iterate over those `ArrayList`s, you are not creating new `ArrayList` objects. Therefore, any change in `al` is reflected in `alal`.

When you assign the reference of an existing object to a new reference variable (as you do in your for loop), you are not creating a new object. The new variable (`al` is your case) merely refers to the existing object.

If you wish to iterate over `alal` without changing the ArrayLists in contains, you must either create a copy of `alal` containing copies of the original ArrayLists, or use a different loop to iterate over `alal` while creating copies :

```
for (int i = 0; i < alal.length; i++) {
    ArrayLst<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>(alal.get(i)); // create copy
    al.set(0, 99);
}
```

Of course, this loop doesn't make much sense, since you are modifying `ArrayList`s that will never be used anywhere. I'm assuming that in your real code you are doing something with the modified `ArrayList`s.

Comment: thanks, I get it now. But how can I create new ArrayList objects and make sure that changes to al won't affect the original variables? Please see my edit above.

Comment: thanks, but please see Edit 2 above. Hmm, why is it that in a normal ArrayList, for the same scanario, new objects are created ? Why don't they refer to the existing object like before?

Comment: @PepperBoy In your second edit you are using assignment (`=`). Assignment can't change the value inside the ArrayList. To make your original code behave like edit 2, you'll have to change `al.set(0, 99);` to `al = new ArrayList<Integer>(); al.add(99);`

Comment: thanks Eran for the help. I appreciate. So, just to confirm, it's the behavior of the set method to change the contents of the original variable. Assignment on the other hand almost treats it like a separate instance. Correct?

Comment: @PepperBoy Yes, the set method changes the contents of the original ArrayList. Assignment to a variable (such as `al = ..`) doesn't affect the contents of the previous object that was referred by that variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are just using the same reference (reference within heap) of an array list with `alal` as the original one `myArrayList1` and `myArrayList2` and hence it acts on the same list and modifies the 0th index element.

If you don't want loop impacting original list, you should do something like:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> alal = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
alal.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(myArrayList1));//creating seperate instance of array list with same content as original list
alal.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(myArrayList2));
```